# Formula for inputting numbers 1, 1.1, 1.2 etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering how to edit this formula to work with row without number. The idea is to put for example `'` in empty row. If there is `'` in previous row, then jump to to the second row above.

prevIWA is a named range and is pointing to previous row (one up) from where the formula is.

prevIWA is `='Agreement'!A125`

Current formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"")));"0.1";IF(ISERROR(FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"`";1)));prevIWA&".1";LEFT(prevIWA;FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"`";1)))&IF(ISERROR(FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"`";2)));VALUE(RIGHT(prevIWA;LEN(prevIWA)-FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"`";1))))+1;VALUE(MID(prevIWA;FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"`";1))+1;(FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"`";2))-FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevIWA;".";"`";1))-1)))+1)))
```

As you can see on row 126 formula does not work, as there is no number on row 125. In this case it should continue from row 124

I have tried to input `IF(prevIWA="'";prevIWA;prevIWA-ROW())` instead of all prevIWA, but it does not work.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Fully working formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"")));"0.1";IF(ISERROR(FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"`";1)));IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA)&".1";LEFT(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"`";1)))&IF(ISERROR(FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"`";2)));VALUE(RIGHT(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);LEN(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA))-FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"`";1))))+1;VALUE(MID(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"`";1))+1;(FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"`";2))-FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(IF(prevIWA="-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 2);prevIWA);".";"`";1))-1)))+1)))
```

Comment: Your formula looks like it can be shortened a lot + you have used a lot of volatile formulas this way using `INDIRECT`. This is going to slow your workbook down. Also, can there be gaps of two cells?

Comment: No gaps of two cells. I am ready for better solution if you have something to offer. HiFo's solution worked however if it is not the best one, we can change the answer to the most efficient way of doing it. Also that others can implement

Comment: So is there another column involved or are the gaps arbitrary?

Comment: No other columns involved. Everything is in column A

Comment: Then maybe I'm just misunderstanding. Where does the gaps come from, why are they there. I understand you put the `'` in there, but why specifically those rows. There must be some sort of rule or reference as to why. Just trying to get the background of this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198790/discussion-between-jvdv-and-user7202022).

Comment: As you can see there are darker row with number 8 and lighter green rows without numbers. In darker green rows there are main topic and in lighter green rows there are sub topics. Numbering should skip sub topics and concentrate on main topics. To identify sub topics I added "-". In main topics there are numbers. I also use this formula for ganttchart positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as discussed in chat, in your case a helper column (or two can come in handy). As discussed (please verify) you don't need to calculate beyond + 0,1 each time so:

In the case of two helper you could set it up like:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,IF(B2<>"","",MAX($C$1:C1)+0.1))
```

In the case of one helper column you could set it up like:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(A2="main",COUNTIF($A$1:A2,"main"),IF(A2="sub","",MAX($B$1:B1)+0.1))
```

It's just examples but the point made is that your current formula can probably be set up smarter/shorter/less volatile :)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(prevIWA="'";prevIWA;prevIWA-ROW())
```

You have made your IF statement wrong. It should be

```
IF(prevIWA="'";INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-2);prevIWA)
```

Use replace in Notepad for example and replace all `prevIWA` by `IF(prevIWA="'";INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-2);prevIWA)` then your formula should be good to go

Comment: Thank you! I have just changed `'` to `-`.